# Can you define a velocity macro to "wrap" other content?

Tags: html, velocity

I'm trying to abstract a common scenario in generated markup where I need a couple of tags to "wrap" an arbitrary content. So instead of writing this

```
<div class="container">
   <p class="someClass">Some header</p>
   <div id="foo">
     <!-- The real content that changes -->
   </div>
</div>
```

I would be able to write something "like"

```
#????
 <!-- The real content that changes
#end
```

Where obviously I don't know what the #???? would be.

As far as I know it is not possible to do this with macros, short of defining a macro for the start of the block and a macro for the end of the block.

```
#macro(startContained)
<div class="container">
   <p class="someClass">Some header</p>
   <div id="foo">
#end

#macro(endContained)
   </div>
</div>
#end

#startContained
<!-- The real content -->
#endContained
```

Any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `#@` macro call syntax, along with the `$!bodyContent` variable:

```
#macro(wrapper)
  <div class="container">
    <p class="someClass">Some header</p>
    <div id="foo">
      $!bodyContent##
    </div>
  </div>
#end

#@wrapper()
  The real content that changes.
#end

#@wrapper()
  Other different content.
#end
```

Renders as:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="someClass">Some header</p>
  <div id="foo">
    The real content that changes.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="someClass">Some header</p>
  <div id="foo">
    Other different content.
  </div>
</div>
```

*(The `##` in the macro body removes trailing whitespace; for HTML it may not matter.)*

Comment: What if the content is HTML? As it is, it will escape it.

Comment: For an explanation of what `!` does in `$!bodyContent`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52163738/4850949)

Comment: It seems like `$bodyContent` cannot contain other macro calls.